# Unchecked typecasting of generic class?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to write a method where I can convert from a string to an enum object at runtime, for a generic enum.  I have a method signature:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Enum<T> foo(String string, Class<T> clazz)
```

However, I am calling it from a class whose generic type parameter does not explicitly extend Enum.  i.e.

```
class bar<X> {
  private Class<X> clazz;
  if (XIsAnEnum()) {
    foo(string, clazz)
  }
}
```

This does not compile because even though I know, from the logic of `XIsAnEnum`, that `X extends Enum<X>`, I don't explicitly state this in the generic type parameter definition, so it is not a valid argument.

Is there a way to do an unchecked cast from `Class<X>` to `Class<X extends Enum<X>>`, or will I have to make a new class `bar2<X extends Enum<X>>` specifically for when I want to use enums?

Comment: I feel like you're missing some code. What you have wouldn't compile because you don't have that if statement in a method.

Comment: Yeah, there's some extra code that would go there in reality, but it doesn't affect the question.

Comment: What do the strings contain? If it's just the name of an enum constant, you can do `MyEnum.valueOf(string)` to get the corresponding `MyEnum` constant and you wouldn't need to write this method.

Comment: String is the name of the constant, but MyEnum is the generic X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Class#asSubclass(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-) to do the cast for you, like

```
foo("value", clazz.asSubclass(Enum.class));
```

This involves an actual verification that `clazz` is referring to a `Class` that is a subclass of `Enum`.

You're throwing out all the generic verification here though.